# Qt : screenshot with QOpenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt5

Hellow,
I have an application based on Qt using QOpenGLWidget.
In the OpenGL widget (named oglwidget in my code) I draw meshes and lines using opengl functions. Then I use QPainter to draw scales and texts in teh same widgte.

Now when I use :

```
const QRect rect(0,0,oglwidget.width(),oglwidget.height());
QPiaxmap pixmap = oglwidget.grab(rect);
```

to save the pixmap in a file with :

```
pixmap.save(...);
```

only the objects drawn with opengl functions are saved.

What do I miss ? Is there any solution to save the entire scene ?

Would you please help ?
Thanks and regards.

Comment: Did you try  `grabFramebuffer`already? (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#grabFramebuffer)

Comment: Hi,
Thank you very much. I tried using "grabFramebuffer" and it resolved my problem.
Regards,
R. Alaie

Answer (score 1):

If you will be using the QOpenGLWidget method for grabbing it will actually get the pixels from the frame buffer rendered by the opengl, if you want to capture the screenshoot you probably should have a look at this [tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html).

To be more specific you probably want the grab method from  QScreen rather then grab on the openGL context (the QOpenGlWidget method).